# Chainlink Functions DON Request: Invalid Contract Address or ENS name

Tags: blockchain, chainlink

Following the Chainlink Functions Getting Started (https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/getting-started) guide, I'm able to deploy contract on Mumbai testnet, and have received my subID/contract address from:

```
npx hardhat functions-sub-create --network polygonMumbai --amount 1 --contract <MyContractAddress>.
```

I'm trying to run the example request to the DON with subID & contract address from above with the command:

```
npx hardhat functions-request --subid 684 --contract <MyContractAddress> --network polygonMumbai
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: invalid contract address or ENS name (argument="addressOrName", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError
```

Double checked the contract output from the `npx hardhat functions-sub-create` call, as well as the subID. Both are correct. Incorrect RPC_URL was suspected, but I'm also able to make earlier calls to testnet with the same key. All previous contract deployments, subscription creation, and functions simulation pass. Node version is 18+.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just tested and everything works again.
Can you make sure you have the latest version?

```
git pull
```

Then make sure all the dependencies are installed.

```
npm install
```

There was a release made yesterday, see the commits [here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit/commits/main). Your issue should be fixed